# creating datetimefield without timezone

Tags: django, postgresql

I need to create datetimefield without timezone, and I need that to be applied on postgres when the tables are created.

I did set the USE_TZ = False. 
But still the field is created with timezone on postgresql.

When I printed the value in django it has no timezone. But when store it does

```
submitted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

also I tried

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
submitted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

on the setting

```
USE_TZ = False
```

when I check the table, the column the column is with time zone.

I deleted the database and recreated it 3 times and still same

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
import datetime
submitted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO since its code only answer.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users –

Comment: Even though I did not see how this can make the change, I did apply it and it is not working.
Thanks